# Can I complete a quest during the "Waterdeep Harbor" phase?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

Can I place an agent in Waterdeep Harbor, complete a quest, and later, after all players have finished, place my agent on another space and complete a second quest?

Using this strategy, a player could potentially complete six (or eight) quests in a turn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. But if you have enough cubes to complete that many missions, you'll probably find the spaces at Waterdeep Harbor filled with enemies playing *mandatory quests* on you...

From the [FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Lords_of_Waterdeep_FAQ):

> Q: When you move (reassign) an agent out of "Waterdeep Harbor" to another building, are you taking another turn? Can you complete a quest?
>   A: You can complete a quest after moving (reassigning) an agent out of "Waterdeep Harbor" - it is another turn.